# How to make XML strings bold, underlined etc?

Tags: android, xml, markup, pretty-print

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/Styles/Font.html

I tried this, along with a lot of things but failed to do so.
Here's what I want.

```
<string name="ss">Bold. Underlined. Italic. Big. Small</string>
```

I want to format a little bit of the string.
Where it's written bold, I want it to be bold...and same for others.

I tried a lot of tags   ...but well nothing worked, and I couldn't find anything on Google or SO.

I know how to do it in a textview, but that's not what I want...

I'm sending some text resource to an activity that shows it...
If I did it with different text views, I'd have to create several of them, a new one for whenever I want bold text, and that's not very elegant.

Is there a way to simple do this in the XML file ? or some other way ?

Comment: A part of the string should have a property like bold or underlined or bigger size... only a part of the string not the entire string.

Answer (score 22):

Try wrapping your marked up text in CDATA tags.  For example:

```
<string name="ss"><![CDATA[<b>Bold.</b> <u>Underlined.</u> <i>Italic.</i> <big>Big.</big> <small>Small</small>]]></string>
```

And then use Html.fromHtml wherever you're wanting to display it:

```
Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.ss))
```

Answer (score 6):

This problem has been driving me crazy for ages. It's something sooo simple that you just want it to work!!!

Anyway I've found an answer here at http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/06/19/styling-text-in-android-through-xml/

The key is to load the resource as a CharSequence using `getResources().getText(R.string.xxxx)` this will retain all the style information and allow you to use inline styling tags.
My mistake was using `getString()` because when loading your resource `getString()` will cause the string to lose all its style information.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use getText you lose the ability to use placeholders such as %s and %d

Answer (score 5):

exemple:

```
<string name="ss"><font size="15"><b>Parrainage</b></font><u>subscribe</u></string>
```

b = bold et u = underline .....etc

Comment: This does work in your res/values/strings.XML, I've done it a thousand times. It is different than HTML tags.

Comment: You have to use getText(string id) instead of getString

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me.

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.</string>

txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.welcome_messages)));
```

more details check Official site: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithSpannables

Answer (score -7):

in dimens file write:

```
<dimen name="size_edittext">180dp</dimen>
```

and in your xml layout or activity call it:

```
android:@dimen/ size_edittext
```

Comment: This is not useful answer. Delete this post.