# Bold text in XML

Tags: xml

I have an XML document where I need some text to be in bold. XML is completely new to me and I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dynamic-widget name="-remote-widget-">
<arg name="componentServiceName">S9RemoteComponentService</arg>
<arg name="strategy">acsStrategy</arg>
<arg name="widgetName">textModule</arg>
<arg name="ref"/>
 
<arg name="acs.roundedImages">true</arg>
<arg name="acs.sectionDivider">gradient</arg>

<arg name="acs.row.1.width">minimum</arg>
<arg name="acs.row.1.hideDivider">false</arg>

<arg name="acs.row.1.markdown">

##A Header
###A title
Some text, but <b>this bit</b> needs to be bold
Some more text
</arg>

</dynamic-widget>
```

How can I make the text wrapped in the `<b>` tags to be bold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make XML strings bold, underlined etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783084/how-to-make-xml-strings-bold-underlined-etc)

Comment: The concept of "bold" does not even exist in XML. XML is not a layout language.

Comment: I believe you have a massive misunderstanding of XML. XML is a meta-language in which you can define application-specific ways of doing things. Maybe your application does define XML tags for making something bold, but without knowing what application that is, there is no way to know. I suggest you restate your question with additional information on what XML-based markup you use, such as “FusionCharts.” Don't forget adding the relevant tags, if they exist.